# Why I always get deleted data from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I am building a simple quiz app using Swift.
My idea is to always get new data from FireBase.
I tried to call function using a button:

```
 @IBAction func Btn5(sender: AnyObject) {
      //delete all data in FireBase
      let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.databse().reference()
      databaseRef.removeValue()
      //refresh the view
      viewDidLoad()
}
```

After I clicked the button, I checked, all data on FireBase is deleted.
However, every time I retrieved the data, it also retrieve the old data (which are already deleted).
I thought it is a simulator problem.
But after I tried to simulate on my iPhone, the old data still persists.

Any ideas to solve it?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: I was storing the value in global variable, that's why I always get the old data. Thanks @Dravidian for the note.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `viewDidLoad`, you should have a function that reloads your UI.

Comment: hi @sbarow: could you show me how to do it? I am still new in Swift. Thanks.

Comment: let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference() databaseRef.child("Posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshop in for child in snapshot.children { if let question = child.value["question"] as ? String { self.Q = question }  if let question = child.value["answer"] as ? String { self.A = answer }  } }

Comment: Are you storing your retrieved data in any of the global variable?

Comment: Oh no. Sorry. Yes, I am storing it on global variable and forgot to make it empty after I call that button. Thanks @Dravidian

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is because the data is downloaded before you delete that node from firebase.. for that you have to refresh your UI or call firebase again to download the data i.e the new data will come next time as previous is removed.

Comment: Any ideas to refresh the UI?

Comment: For that it depends on how you are displaying data to user.. please add the code for that..

Comment: let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference() databaseRef.child("Posts").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshop in for child in snapshot.children { if let question = child.value["question"] as ? String { self.Q = question } if let question = child.value["answer"] as ? String { self.A = answer } } }

Comment: add it in your question above n whole of it

Comment: Sorry, I was storing the value in global variable, that's why I always get the old data.